# JavaScript: Function not getting called

Tags: javascript, function

I'm having problems calling the function `calculateAndDisplayRoute(1)` at the end of this function. I checked on FireFox Developer, and found that all of the other code is executed correctly, except for this line. Can anyone see any problems?

```
function adjustHex(diff, total) {
    //....
    var nearest = total;

    for (var i = 0; i < eightPoints.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < eightPoints.length; j++) {
            //....
            checkThisHex(tempPoint1, tempPoint2, 2, function (current) {
                var bool = compareHex(current, nearest); // returns true if current is closer than the nearest

                if (bool == true) {
                    document.getElementById("printInfo3").innerHTML = current;
                    nearest = current;
                    fillWaypts(tempPoint1, tempPoint2);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    calculateAndDisplayRoute(1);
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and found no error, it usually called the 'calculateAndDisplayRoute' function, of some error in the console?

Comment: If you use the debug feature of Firefox Developer or Google Console you should be able to follow the code execution where the function end or if you get any errors. As Geander said, i don't think it's anything wrong in the javascript code you pasted. It's likely you get an error somewhere which breaks the exection.

Comment: You haven't defined calculateAndDisplayRoute here.